# Problems with facebook ads sdk

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-ads-api

I am making react native expo app. I wanted to add FB ads to my app. I have done all like in the docs, but it gives me an error:

```
"errorCode": 1203,
"errorMessage": "The SDK version in the ad request is no longer supported for new apps. Please upgrade to one of the latest versions of the SDK",
```

},

How I can download the latest fd ads SDK? I downloaded SDK from this page:

https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-ads-facebook

I am using expo sdk 33. Please help me. I need it very much

Code:

```html
// page.js
import React from 'react';

import { View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import * as FacebookAds from 'expo-ads-facebook';

import AdScreenFacebook from './AdScreenFacebook'

const adsManager = new FacebookAds.NativeAdsManager("2272791379702600_2272795453035526", 10);

class AdScreen extends React.Component {
  render () {
          return (
  <View>
  <AdScreenFacebook adsManager={adsManager} />

  <FacebookAds.BannerAd
      placementId="2272791379702600_2272803043034767"
      type="standard"
      onPress={() => console.log('click')}
      onError={error => console.log('error', error)}
    />
    </View>
          );
      }

 }


  export default createStackNavigator(
    {
      Main: {
        screen: AdScreen,
      },
      AdScreenFacebook: {
        screen: AdScreenFacebook,
      }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Main',
    }
  );
  
  // AdScreenFacebook.js
  
  import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import * as FacebookAds from 'expo-ads-facebook';
const { AdTriggerView, AdMediaView, AdIconView } = FacebookAds;


class AdScreenFacebook extends React.Component {
  render () {
          return (
            <View style={{  flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',}}>
            <View style={{ width:500}}>
                   <AdMediaView style={{ width: 160, height: 90 }}/>
                   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                   <AdIconView style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}/>
                   <AdTriggerView>
                     <Text>{this.props.nativeAd.bodyText}</Text>
                       <Text>{this.props.nativeAd.callToActionText}</Text>
                   </AdTriggerView>
                 </View>
                  </View>
                    </View>
    );
      }

 }


export default FacebookAds.withNativeAd(AdScreenFacebook);
```

Comment: Are you `expo init` project?

Comment: @hong develop yes

Comment: @TopWorld  any solution for this error ?